# Bit masking with hexadecimal in c++

Tags: c++, masking

I need to mask my output in binary with hexadecimals variables. Do I need to convert the binary output to hexadecimal (or hexadecimals variables to binary)? Or is there any way in C++ to directly mask them and store it to a new variable?

#Edit : The binary output is stored to a `std::bitset` variable.

Comment: Values are stored in memory in binary anyway so 10 & 0b01 (decimal with binary AND) will work just as well as 0xFE & 1 (hexadecimal AND decimal). Etc... It is no more complicated then that. So just use integers in code and do bitwise operations on them. 
https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/bit-manipulation-with-bitwise-operators-and-bit-masks/

Comment: Hi, thank you for your comment. But my output is stored in a variable declared as std::bitset. I've tried to directly mask it with the hex, but it gave me an error.

Comment: It would help if you didn't add this info as comments but add some code (even if it doesn't compile yet) in your question instead. As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask]. I guess https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset could be of use for you. Just convert whatever number you have to a `bitset` and then do the operation between the two `bitset`s.

Answer (score 0):

The use of bitset wasn't mentioned in your question, improve on that next time.
You need to create a bitmask for the hex value as well. Then you can just & the bitmasks

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::bitset<8> value{ 0x03 };
    std::bitset<8> mask{ 0x01 };
    std::bitset<8> masked_value = value & mask;

    std::cout << value.to_string() << " & " << mask.to_string() << " = " << masked_value.to_string() << "\n";
}
```